# PowerShell run as administrator

Tags: powershell, admin

I am experiencing below issue when I run the batch script as administrator. When I
ran the same script normally, there were no issues.

Please share some thoughts on this issue.

[snapshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUHxl.png)

Comment: Are you sure that the script is in the current working directory?

Comment: Please do not post a link of a picture of an error. Copy and paste the error message into your question instead.

Comment: @marc, share the code here, please so we can analyze further ?

Answer (score 5):

When you run as administrator, the user session changes from your user session to one based in `%SystemRoot%\System32`. What you need to do is get the path of the current invocation of your Powershell script and make it the path of your `build1.ps1` script:

```
$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName
& "$ScriptPath\build1.ps1" -Target prepare-qa
```

This way, regardless of user, the script is executed in the proper location.

Answer (score 1):

When you open powershell as a user, the default directory is `C:\Users\MyName`.

When you open powershell as an admin, the default directory is `C:\WINDOWS\System32`.

In your script, try using `Set-Location C:\Users\myusername` or where ever your script is located. Or, fully qualify the script's path.